# How do i create a sed script to prompt the user to replace a number in a file?

Tags: sed, awk, scripting, grep, replace

I'm new in Unix, and I'm learning about sed command. I need to write a very small script for searching a number in a file and replacing it. I tried doing grep, and than deleting the specific phone number from a file, and then adding another one. But i was told that i can use sed in a script to replace. I know how to use the sed command on a command line for search, and replacing something. But how do i write a script, which lets the user search a number, and then let the user enter the number which they want to replace the old number with.

So far what i did was use grep to find a number, that works. but now I'm stuck at how can i let the user add in the new number, so the new number can replace the old one. I tried piping grep to sed, and vice versa. No luck so far. I sound redundant, :/ but I'm really frustrated. Any help will be appreciated :D.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and your desired output from that..

Comment: not a duplicate, OP asked about geting new phone number.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starting point for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

PHONEFILE=/path/to/your/file

# Prompt for search and replace numbers
# and simply exit if either is empty
# (in your actual script, you'll need to flesh this out with
# proper validation of phone number formats, error messages etc.!)
read -p "Number to search for: " oldnum
if [ ! "$oldnum" ]; then exit; fi

read -p "Replace with number: " newnum
if [ ! "$newnum" ]; then exit; fi

# Search and replace, change the phone file directly
# and create a backup of the previous version with .bak extension
# This assumes a file containing one phone number per line
sed -i .bak 's/^'"$oldnum"'$/'"$newnum"'/' $PHONEFILE
```

Comment: It also assumes BSD `sed`, and assumes that you won't change the value of `PHONEFILE` to something with special characters in it (since you [didn't quote it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943) in the final line).

Comment: I'm not sure why you use Bash above, rather than something less heavyweight, but since you do, is there a good reason to prefer `echo; read` over `read -p`?  Just wondering.

Comment: @TobySpeight Since the OP stated that she's new in Unix and I don't know where she wants to go from here with her script, I would recommend `bash` to her for the built-in convenience, just in case. Also, this did not seem to me like a time or memory-critical application which would demand the use of a lightweight shell per se (the weight-lifting is done by `sed` alone, not by the surrounding script… at this stage).

Comment: @TobySpeight And you're right about the `read -p`. I updated this, thanks. Bad PHP habits…

Comment: That seems a good reason to use Bash - I just wanted to point out (for didactic purposes) that one can/should choose which shell to use for each script.

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't knew how to start it. This should really help.